# Copy sheet to another workbook in VBA does not copy

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a specific sheet from one workbook to another but it seems that it does not copy the content of the sheet and returns an empty one.

Second problem is that when I copy the sheet I use `Sheet.Count` to create another sheet in my workbook where I paste the new sheet but it is not working properly as it does not create a new one as and instead takes my last one and renames it and then deletes it.

What could it be wrong and how do I add error handling code?

```
Sheets(filesheet).COPY After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

'Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
wb.Close savechanges:=False

'naming of the copied sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Imported data"

'copy the material as values to sourcing template sheet
Sheets("Imported data").Cells.COPY
Sheets("Sourcing template").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'delete the imported copied sheet (named ranges etc, to avoid file size growing too much)
Sheets("Imported data").Delete
```

Comment: If you use Sheets without specifying the workbook, it defaults to the active workbook. You frequently use Sheets here, but only a couple times do you specify the workbook. Try always specifying the workbook.

Comment: The problem is that it works for one file but not for the others i am using. what would be the problem?

Comment: are you copying two sheets or just the one. As fare as i can see you first copy `filesheet`to the end then you copy a New sheet `imported data`, which has no data, to `sourcing template`. Or am i missing something?

Comment: As @RichHolton said, always prefix the usages of `Sheets` with the workbook, otherwise you're implicitly referring to the active workbook, so use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(filesheet).COPY After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Comment: @krib i am copying filesheet to the end and then i rename this "imported data" copy it to the "sourcing template" sheet and then delete it. But here there are 2 problems: first, it copies no data and second it does not copy to the end so then it renames my last sheet as "imported data"

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of problems here but ill try to explain some....

1. Dont copy and paste. You thisCell.Value = ThatCell.Value instead.
2. Referencing Active(whatever) is going to eventually lead you to bad results. It may seem like a pain point to type more, but explicitly spelling it out what workbook/sheet/whatever you are intending to reference will solve alot of frustration in the future.

Here is most likely how i'd approach this like this. This is easily modified to do all sheets in a work book.

```
Dim sheetCopy as variant
dim sheet as Worksheet
dim rowC as long
dim colC as long

set sheet = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Imported Data")

rowC = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
colC = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
sheetCopy = sheet.UsedRange

ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sourcing template").Range(ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sourcing template").Cells(1,1), ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sourcing template").Cells(rowC,colC).Value2 = sheetCopy

sheet.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, I don't fully understand your question.

But base on my understanding, this code works for me. The `filesheet` in `Sheets(filesheet)` doesn't make sense for me, so I've changed it to `"Sheet1"`. You can change it ot your exact sheet name.

```
Sub test()


Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Imported Data"

Sheets("Imported data").Cells.Copy
Sheets("Sourcing template").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Imported data").Delete

End Sub
```

The code copy all the content of Sheet1 to new sheet and change the new sheet name as "Imported data".

Then, copy all cells in "Imported data" and paste only the values to "Sourcing template". Thus, only values will be shown in "Sourcing template" (any chart or table will be ignored).

If you wish to paste all the content including formatting, you should use `Activesheets.Paste` instead.